# How would I add an extra column of information from a postgres query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

So let's say I had two tables:

Classes

- id

and

Students

- id
- classId
- Name

How would I query this such that my return is like this

Classroom {

- id
- listOfStudents: Student[]

}[]

I know how to do basic joins and everything, but I have no clue how to insert something like that extra column to the return value.

Answer (score 0):

You need a LEFT JOIN, GROUP BY and [`array_agg`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html)

```sql
SELECT 
  class.id, 
  CASE
    WHEN array_agg(student.id) = '{NULL}' THEN '{}'
    ELSE array_agg(student.id)
  END AS listOfStudents 
FROM 
  class 
  LEFT JOIN student ON student.classId = class.id 
GROUP BY 
  class.id
```

LEFT JOIN ensures classes that do not have any students linked are also listed in the final result.